# .npmignore ignored when installing local module

Tags: npm

All our server projects contain a git submodule folder (let's say `modules`), which contains our custom modules/components.

Such module dependencies are installed locally (see `serverApp/package.json`) so that we don't have to include the whole submodule folder to the final rpm. What I'm having trouble with is limiting the number of files included in `node_modules`.

The submodule structure looks like the following:

```
modules
|--loader
   |--dist => compiled js files here that are created when installing the module
   |--ts => contains typescript files that shouldn't be included in node_modules
   |--package.json
   |--tsconfig.json
|--more modules
|--.gitignore
```

Adding an `.npmignore` file inside `modules/loader` doesn't seem to help as the whole folder is copied.

`modules/loader/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

`modules/loader/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "loader",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm run build",
    "build": "../../node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^3.9.3",
    "@types/nomnom": "0.0.28",
    "@types/yamljs": "^0.2.30",
    "lodash": "^3.9.3",
    "nomnom": "^1.8.1",
    "yamljs": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "~2.3.4"
  }
}
```

`serverApp/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-server-app",
  "version": "2.3.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "myServerApp.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "private",
  "dependencies": {
    "loader": "file:modules/loader"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if it has to do with the fact that we have a [`.gitignore` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) or because the module is not published and installed locally.

npm version => 5.3.0

**EDIT**

Doesn't work with specifying the `"files"` in `modules/loader/package.json` either

Answer (score 1):

As after checkout the issue I found out below useful points which need to mention out :

We use a **.npmignore** file to keep stuff out of your package.
If there's no **.npmignore** file, but there is a **.gitignore** file, then npm will ignore the stuff matched by the .gitignore file.

If you want to include something that is excluded by your **.gitignore** file, you can create an empty **.npmignore** file to override it.
Like git, npm looks for **.npmignore** and **.gitignore** files in all subdirectories of your package, not only the root directory.

Similar to .gitignore file .npmignore also follow these rules

> Blank lines or lines starting with **#** are ignored & Standard glob patterns work.
>
> You can end patterns with a forward slash **/** to specify a directory.
>
> You can negate a pattern by starting it with an exclamation point **!.**
>
> By default, the following paths and files are  ignored, so there's no need to add them to **.npmignore** explicitly

Additionally, everything in node_modules is ignored, except for bundled dependencies. npm automatically handles this for you, so don't bother adding node_modules to **.npmignore**.

**Testing whether your .npmignore or files config works**

If you want to double check that your package will include only the files you intend it to when published, you can run the **npm pack command** locally which will generate a tarball in the working directory, the same way it does for publishing.

And you can also checkout same issue here [Consider methodologies for reducing the number of files within `node_modules` #14872](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/14872)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked with `node 0.6.13 / npm 1.1.9`? This issue is common in `npm 1.1.4` .
have a look on this [link](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2144)

Comment: I'm not using `npm 1.1.4`. The used version is `5.3.0`. I can't really change the version

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you do not want to include "whole submodule" into the "final rpm", by which I presume the package you will finally prepare. I reproduced similar setup and added a '.npmignore' to ignore "submodule" which I installed using `npm install --save ./task_in` where 'task_in' was my module kept along side of the main package's('task') 'package.json'.

And when the final package was prepared using `npm pack` while being in the 'task' folder, I got a package(a tar file) without the folder('task_in') as indicated in the '.npmignore'.

While working, though, I found that the module 'task_in' folder was copied to 'node_modules' which is automatically not included in the final package( refer [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package)). Also, while the package is prepared, ".gitignore" is over-ridden by ".npmignore".

So, this is my "two cents" and I hope it helps you.

Comment: We are not using `npm pack` but we create the rpm with Grunt

Comment: How are you making rpm using grunt ? Any plugins ?

Comment: Mainly `grunt-easy-rpm`

Comment: For configuring grunt-easy-rpm, try excluding the files using "excludeFiles" key in the grunt configuration file, (look in docs - https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-easy-rpm#excluding-files).

Comment: But the folders are already added to `node_modules` even before creating the rpm. I cannot hardcode each folder from each module. The problem is with npm. It shouldn't copy the folders in the first place